# Editing questions with single character tags fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, ios-app

When using version 1.0.1 of the iOS app it is not possible to edit question that have tags with only one character (e.g. `c` or `r`). After clicking `Submit` the user is thrown to the tags page and the following error popup is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the screenshot shows, for some reason we had a requirement on the app-side that at least two characters were required. Clearly that was wrong, so I've removed it.

The fix should be available on version **1.0.2**